# How much memory does one Postgresql savepoint take up?

Tags: postgresql, memory-usage

How much memory does a single savepoint (within a transaction) take up in postgresql? I'm developing an application which might create a significant amount of savepoints (100k+) and was wondering about the performance penalty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know they are very cheap, just like transactions are in general. But I have never tried creating 100k of them.

You should be aware that there is a limit on the size of a transaction (at most 2^32-1 commands, if I recall correctly) which it sounds like you are getting close to hitting with your design. In general, I would probably consider a design with hundreds of thousands of save-points flawed.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is best answered by trying it out in your particular application.  It's not much per individual savepoints, but when you are talking 100k+, the effects will accumulate and other factors can come into play as well.